# How to active git hook post-receive in a forced push?

Tags: git, git-push

I am deploying my app using GIT.

In my server I have a hook post-receive that updates the files of the application on push events.

My problem is when I push a new commit the files are updated, but if I amend to a commit and push with the force flag. The remote repository is updated but the files aren't. It seems that post-receive in this case is not called.

The post-receive file:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/ --git-dir=/var/repo/test.git/ checkout -f dev
```

Comment: The `post-receive` hook is called in all cases where the push succeeds, even when there's a force push.

Comment: Well, I just test it again and I had the success msg from git but the files didn't change.

Comment: Try running `git --work-tree=/var/www/ --git-dir=/var/repo/test.git/ rev-parse dev` both before and after to verify that the branch has different values before and after.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I just tried the new command but it was the same, no update on work-tree files.

Comment: It's not supposed to change the behavior; it's diagnostic to try to identify the problem.  Do you see different values before and after your force push, or the same values?

Comment: Ok, I got different values after the push -f. I don't know if it helps but I have root access to the server.

Comment: After some tests it seems the issue is not in post receive but in the amend process. You are right about post-receive. I am doing more tests when I solve it I'll post it.